# Javascript: build css linear gradient with separator between strip

Tags: javascript, css

I have this code for build a linear gradient by array of colors (**unknown length**):

```js
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'violet'];
const strips = [];
let start = 0;
let end  = 0;
const stripPerc = Math.ceil(100 / colors.length);
for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  const color = colors[i];
  start = end;
  end   = start + stripPerc;

  if ( end > 100 ) {
    end = 100;
  }

  let strip = color + ' ';
  strip += start + '% ';
  strip += end + '% ';

  strips.push(strip.trim());
}
document.getElementById('foo').style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(135deg, ' + strips.join(',') + ')';
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

i want add a small (1%) white stripe between the colors:

```js
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'violet'];
const strips = [];
let start = 0;
let end  = 0;
const stripPerc = Math.ceil(100 / colors.length);
for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  const color = colors[i];
  start = end;
  end   = start + stripPerc;

  if ( end > 100 ) {
    end = 100;
  }

  let strip = color + ' ';
  strip += start + '% ';
  strip += end + '% ';

  strips.push(strip.trim());
  
  strips.push(' white ' + end + '% '+ (end+1) +'%');
  end++;
}
document.getElementById('foo').style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(135deg, ' + strips.join(',') + ')';
```

```css
div {
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

it works, but now the total length is over the 100%. How fix it?

Comment: Do you mean white ones of the same size as colored? Or that your last stripe is 2% less width? (approximately, taking in account that white ones are 1% each and you don't take them into account calculating `stripPerc`)

Comment: no, i mean all colored are the same size, each withe are only 1%, and the total is 100%. Now the tortal is 105 %

Comment: Assuming white spaces will be 1% you could use this `const stripPerc = Math.ceil((100 - colors.length) / colors.length);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refactored your code a little bit, but logic is the same as expected - you should take in account white stripes width to calculate colored stripes width https://jsbin.com/supikoz/edit?html,js,output

```
const coloredWidth = 100 - stripWidth * (colors.length - 1);
const stripPerc = Math.ceil( coloredWidth / colors.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for this. Accodording to your needs, you can style it or add white space. The trick is to use space-between. I would recommend doing the calculation with js and the placement with css.

```js
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'violet'];
const stripPerc = Math.ceil(100 / colors.length) - 1;

colors.forEach(color => {
  let strip_element = document.createElement('div');
  strip_element.style.background = color;
  strip_element.style.width = stripPerc + '%';
  
  document.getElementById('flex').appendChild(strip_element);
})
```

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id='flex'>
</div>
```

Comment: Author's version is more flexible :) Much less DOM elements, no manual css-width calculations required. And, by the way, children don't need `height` as it's flex. By default they stretch

Comment: @Anarion Op could combine the answers. I would stil use flexbox in the end to solve the spacing issues. I see now that the array is of unknown length indeed. Thnx for the tip btw, was not sure if it was needed, but put it in there anyway to make sure it did stretch ;)

Comment: @Anarion Was in a rush earlier, but updated my answer. This is what I meant with combining the answers. Cleaner and simpler.

Comment: Now it's much better. Though I'd prefer linear gradient. Less DOM, also your divs may have issues when you'll try to skew them. While background is a background and you can easily put any content over it. Divs version may have chance only if you'd like to animate it somehow.